# Sumar Genéricos

Tags: java

Estoy intentando sumar dos genéricos en una clase abstracta heredada de Number, pero no me lo permite, me gustaria arreglarlo

```
public abstract class MatrizGenerica<E extends Number> {
    // Crear array genérico E[][] arrayGenerico = (E[][]) new Number[5][5];
    protected abstract E sumar(E o1, E o2);

    protected abstract E multiplicar(E o1, E o2);

    protected abstract E cero();

    public E[][] sumarMatrices(E[][] matriz1, E[][] matriz2){
        if((matriz1.length != matriz2.length) && (matriz1[0].length != matriz2[0].length)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Las matrices no tienen el mismo tamaño");
        }
        //Crear array generico

        E[][] genericArray = (E[][]) new Number[matriz1.length][matriz1[0].length]; 
        for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz1.length; filas++) {
            for (int columnas = 0; columnas < matriz1[filas].length; columnas++) {
                genericArray[filas][columnas] = (matriz1[filas][columnas]).doubleValue() + 
                        (matriz2[filas][columnas]).doubleValue();
                //new Double(String.valueOf(o1))
            }
        }
        return genericArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Los genéricos de Java tienen limitaciones, así que te indico cómo podrías hacerlo funcionar:

- Como el genérico `E` ha de ser `Number` o una clase hija, estás limitado a los métodos provistos por la clase Number. Eso significa que no tienes métodos para hacer operaciones con ellos, a menos que los transformes primero a números primitivos (lo que ya haces con `doubleValue()`).
- El problema es que no estás creando un nuevo elemento del tipo Double, y el autoboxing no te funcionará, ya que el compilador no es tan inteligente como para saber que el tipo E es Number y que Double es un Number. Podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

  ```
  genericArray[filas][columnas] = new Double(
        (matriz1[filas][columnas]).doubleValue() +
        (matriz2[filas][columnas]).doubleValue());
  ```

  Y compilaría, pero te va a dar un error en ejecución siempre que `matriz1` y `matriz2` no sean `Double`, porque el resultado ha de ser de la misma clase que los dos inputs. Podríamos intentar solucionarlo así:

  ```
  public abstract class MatrizGenerica<E extends Number> {

      //otros métodos abstractos que he eliminado por simplicidad

      public E[][] sumarMatrices(E[][] matriz1, E[][] matriz2){
          if((matriz1.length != matriz2.length) && (matriz1[0].length != matriz2[0].length)) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Las matrices no tienen el mismo tamaño");
          }
          E n= matriz1[0][0];
          Class<? extends Number> clazz=n.getClass();
          E[][] genericArray = generaMatriz(clazz, matriz1.length, matriz1[0].length); 
          for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz1.length; filas++) {
              for (int columnas = 0; columnas < matriz1[filas].length; columnas++) {
                  double suma= (matriz1[filas][columnas]).doubleValue() + 
                          (matriz2[filas][columnas]).doubleValue();

                  genericArray[filas][columnas] = generaNumber(suma, clazz);
                  //new Double(String.valueOf(o1))
              }
          }
          return genericArray;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      private E generaNumber(double suma, Class<? extends Number> clazz) {
          if (clazz == Double.class) {
              return (E) new Double(suma);
          }
          if (clazz == Integer.class) {
              return (E) new Integer((int) suma); //perderá decimales, si los hay
          }
          // ... otras opciones


          return (E) new BigDecimal(suma);
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      private E[][] generaMatriz(Class c, int rows, int columns) {

          Class<? extends Number[]> clazz= ((E[]) Array.newInstance(c,0)).getClass();
          E[][] matrix = (E[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, rows);
          for (int i=0;i< matrix.length; i++) {
              matrix[i] = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, columns);
          }
          return matrix;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          MatrizGenerica<Integer> mg = new MatrizGenerica<Integer>() {};
          Integer[][] m1 = {{1,2},{1,2}};
          Integer[][] m2 = {{1,2},{1,2}};
          Integer[][] r = mg.sumarMatrices(m1,m2);
          System.out.print(r[0][0]);
      }


  }
  ```

Como ves, crear un objeto con genéricos es bastante enrevesado: Algo como

```
E[][] matriz = new E[n][m];
```

da un error de compilación, puesto que no se puede crear un array de genéricos.

Devolver un array de Number, como intentas, tampoco funciona porque devuelves un tipo disntinto a E, así que he creado un método para generar cada elemento de tu matriz y otro para generar la matriz misma, conociendo la clase de las matrices recibidas.